# Why does Wordpress Woocommerce Customer data disappear when I search for it

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function which creates a custom post when A new user is registered. I want to add custom meta tags to this post which are based on the user just created. For some reason, I cannot get any custom user meta tags when I look for them in this function.

I just used `$customer = new WC_Customer($author_id);` and it displays every single custom meta tag that I've been searching for.

However, I might just be dumb, but I don't know how to access this data.

```
    // Get author ID
       $author_id = get_post_field('post_author', $post_ID);
       $author_info = get_userdata($author_id);

       $customer = new WC_Customer($author_id);

    // Add meta tags
       add_post_meta($post_ID, 'a_woocommerce_test_1', $customer, true);
       add_post_meta($post_ID, 'a_woocommerce_test_2', $customer->data, true);
       add_post_meta($post_ID, 'a_woocommerce_test_3', $customer->get_data(), true);
       add_post_meta($post_ID, 'a_woocommerce_test_5', $customer->get_meta_data(), true);
       add_post_meta($post_ID, 'a_woocommerce_test_6', $customer->get_shipping(), true);
       add_post_meta($post_ID, 'a_woocommerce_test_7', $customer->get_billing(), true);
```

The first test displays all customer information which is great. So I tried to access it, but all the data returns empty ''.

As stated I have tried a number of different add_post_meta functions with different $meta_values, but they all return empty ''.

Thank you